# Robust selector to find all elements of class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get all elements who have a class that begins with `vd-`? My code below works for most cases except for the following:

```
class="foo vd-bar"
```

It works for these cases:

```
class="vd-bar foo"
```

Here is my selector, will it work if the HTML markup uses single quotation marks? For eg; `class='vd-foo'`?

```
$('[class^="vd-"]', myElement).each(function(index, ele) {


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the contains selector (`*`), not the start with selector (`^`). Other than that, it doesn't really matter whether you use single or double quotes as long as you match them correctly. Here is an example:

```js
$("[class*='vd-']").css("border", "1px solid #f00");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo vd-bar">first div</div>
<div class='vd-bar foo'>second div</div>
<div class='fvd-bar foo'>third div</div>
```

Note: As you can see, the code above will select everything that contains "vd-". That should be fine for most cases because usually class prefixes don't occur in the middle of the class name. If they do, that's considered a bad design. If you want to only select elements with classes that start with "vd-", that cannot be done in a simple selector, so you'll have to use two selectors like randomir's answer below. That has a performance cost in big documents, so it is better to avoid it unless it is necessary. Here is a jQuery example:

```js
$("[class*=' vd-'],[class^='vd-']").css("border", "1px solid #f00");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo vd-bar">first div</div>
<div class='vd-bar foo'>second div</div>
<div class='fvd-bar foo'>third div</div>
```

Comment: will the class "fvd-bar" be selected?

Comment: yes, anything that contains "vd-" will be selected. I've added it to my example.

Comment: I don't believe the OP wants to select elements with classnames like `thisisnot-vd-class`.

Comment: Please read the first sentence of the question: "How can I get all elements who have a **class that begins with** `vd-`".

Comment: @randomir Although you're technically correct when reading the question literally, but usually class prefixes don't occur in the middle of the class name. If they do, that's considered a bad design. As you know, having two selectors like in your answer has an obvious performance cost in big documents, so it is better to avoid it unless it is necessary. However, just for the completeness of the accepted answer, I've referenced your answer and added an example.

Comment: @randomir I don't have much time to do tests, so it's nice that you added one to your answer. However, your test is flawed and your results interpretation is incorrect. Your HTML is only one line, where do you ever have a web page with one line? You need a full page with several matches. Anyway, I ran your test and got 566 / 839, so that's a 32%, not 2% - 7% as you interpreted it. It doesn't really need test, just think about it for a moment, you're effectively doing two searches instead of one, it's therefore expected to have a noticeable impact.

Comment: @randomir More importantly, you started with a flawed assumption *knowingly sacrificing the accuracy and accepting mismatches*, how is that ever correct? You're not adding JavaScript or CSS to some unknown page, you're adding it to your own page. There is not sacrifice or mismatches. A solution either works for your purpose or doesn't, in which case you use another one. It's as simple as that. If my simpler and faster answer does the job for your page (majority of cases), then you should use it, otherwise you should use yours regardless of the performance.

Comment: @RacilHilan, please check the **setup and teardown code for each test**. I'm creating 500 elements inside that `<ul>` you saw, they look like this: `<li class="prefix-class infix-class suffix-class">List Item 296</li>`. In which browser are you running the test? I've just got 8575/8093 (that's 6% difference), in a slow Firefox.

Comment: @RacilHilan, the OP never said he's adding code to *his* page.

Comment: @randomir I'm sorry, I really don't have time for tests. Yes, I didn't notice that you created 500 elements in JS, that makes it better. As for the result, even if the difference is 6%, it's only one factor. It's a simple logic, 2 searches instead of one. You assumed FireFox to be a slow one (actually IE is probably slower), but have you considered mobile browsers? Finally, your last comment *the OP never said he's adding code to his page* is just pointless. By *your page* I meant that you know the code on the page and you know if one solution works or not.

Comment: @RacilHilan, have you considered he's creating a widget, or a script meant to be embedded in 3rd party sites?

Comment: @randomir No, I haven't and I didn't need to. Read my answer and comments carefully. **You must select the solution that works for your purpose**, so in the cases you mentioned, you must select your solution not mine regardless of the performance. However, a widget or generic script that is selecting partial classes is very unlikely, but if it happens to be the case and you cannot guarantee that the prefix doesn't appear in the middle (which is also very unlikely), then use your solution. As you can see, it's only needed in edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, CSS [Level 3 attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) are very limited (and [Level 4 in draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#attribute-selectors) are not much better).

You will have to use a combination of infix-match and prefix-match attribute selectors to achieve a robust selection of all elements with a class that begins with `vd-`:

```
[class*=" vd-"], [class^="vd-"] {
    ...
}
```

The first one will select elements with value of attribute `class` containing `<space>vd-` (cases like `foo vd-...`) and the second one will patch the corner case of `vd-` class being the first one (cases like `vd-bar foo`).

### Performance

One might be tempted to use *only infix* (substring) selector, on account of assumed performance penalty incurred by usage of double attribute selectors (infix and prefix match), knowingly sacrificing the accuracy and accepting mismatches like [`yrivd-button`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yrivd) for `vd-button`.

However, [measurements show](https://jsperf.com/css-attribute-selectors-from-javascript/) there is **no** statistically significant **difference** in performance between **only infix** match selector **and** the combined **infix+prefix** match selector (compare `substringMatch` and `classPrefixSelector` on [`jsperf.com`](https://jsperf.com/css-attribute-selectors-from-javascript/) test).

The combined selector is only **2% to 7% slower** (depending on browser) than a single attribute value match selector.

If someone is concerned about that, she shouldn't use attribute selectors at all, but only class selectors `.vd-name`, **which are 2 to 3 times faster** than any of the attribute selectors (including the simplest one `[attr]`, which only tests for attribute existence).